# Graphing Multiple Graphs on One Graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

In python, I have the following function for creating the Mendenhall's Characteristic Curves of Composition

```
def mendenhall(toks):
  dist = nltk.FreqDist([len(w) for w in toks])
  x = sorted(dist.keys())
  y = [dist[i] for i in x]
  return x, y
```

Then I created the following graphs using it

```
x,y = mendenhall((nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories='romance')))
plt.plot(x,y)
```

and

```
x,y = mendenhall((nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories='mystery')))
plt.plot(x,y)
```

but is there a way to put these two on a graph together, or do they have to be seperate?

Comment: Have you tried it?  Do both `plot` calls before doing the `show`.  The matplotlib documentation is very extensive.

Comment: I have tried but no success yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an existence proof that what I said works:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y1 = [6,7,8,9,10]
y2 = [7,6,5,4,3]

plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.show()
```

So, in your case:

```
x,y = mendenhall((nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories='romance')))
plt.plot(x,y)
x,y = mendenhall((nltk.corpus.brown.words(categories='mystery')))
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Of course, if the x axes are not the same, the results will not overlap.

Comment: I was confused, but now that I see it, you are right. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way to choose the color for each line and/or add a legion?

Comment: Of course, but you need to read the documentation or look for examples.